# Как сделать массовый кик пользователя из всех бесед

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Я новичок в php, у меня вопрос как сделать кик пользователя со всех бесед вконтакте где тот состоит ниже скриншот отправлю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы дали очень мало информации касательно проблемы которая у вас возникла, но попытаюсь помочь. Предполагая, что у Вас уже есть какой-то скрипт с ключами к API VK ([Быстрый старт для использования VK API](https://dev.vk.com/ru/api/getting-started))

Вы можете кикнуть юзера, с помощью `messages.removeChatUser`

Вот обработка самого сообщения. **Кик из беседы по команде /kick**

```
if ($data->type == 'message_new') { // Если это новое сообщение то выполняем код указанный в условии


    if (mb_substr($message,0,5) == '/kick'){ // Обрезаем сообщение и сравниваем что получилось

        $kick_id = mb_substr($message ,6); // еще раз обрезаем и получаем все что написано после /kick_
        $vk->request('messages.removeChatUser', ['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'member_id' => $kick_id]);
        $vk->sendMessage($peer_id, "id - {$kick_id} был исключен :-)");

    }


}
```

[Ссылка на документацию](https://dev.vk.com/ru/method/messages.removeChatUser)

Comment: Это кик с 1 беседы, а я имею введу, "если человек состоит в нескольких беседах где будет мой бот при вводе /kickall он будет кикать со всех бесед вк"

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос информацию о ваших попытках, добавьте ваш код и конкретно проблему, что у Вас не получилось.

Comment: я сделал только обычную команду кик как у вас, чисто теоретически я не знаю как её сделать эту команду

Comment: так же у меня ид бесед находятся на бд

Comment: Так в чем проблема? Проитерируйте список всех чатов из которых нужно удалить юзера и отправьте messages.removeChatUser для каждого из этих чатов

Comment: так я не понимаю как это сделать, если пример может быть?

Comment: for element in collection: // итерируем список idшников
    // делаем request

Comment: for element in collection:
{
 $vk->request('messages.removeChatUser', ['chat_id' => список ид, 
 'member_id' => $kick_id]);
}
так?